# How to get a HTML Form to query and produce results from Mysql datebase

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have created a form that has one text field and one select box, I also have created a button. Now what I want to happen is when the button is pressed I want the string in the forms to be matched up to my database and then I want the results of those matches to be returned and shown on the screen.

For example if I was to type 'History' into my text field box and I also selected 'level 2' from my select box when the button (Submit Button) was pressed I would want returned on the page everything that matches up with the word history and the selection of level 2 in my database.

I know that I have to connect my page with my Database through PHP and I have successfully done that, but what I don't understand is how to then get my HTML Form to Query the database and provide results back onto the screen

In terms of a example website that is very similar to the concept I would like to create take a look at this webpage. http://search.ucas.com/cgi-bin/hsrun/search/search/search.hjx;start=search.HsSearch.run?y=2013&w=H (UCAS Course Search) this website has multiple text fields and select boxes and a submit button exactly as I am trying to create and the results provided are only the results that match with what has been searched.

The code below works in terms of it links my text-field to my database but I can't get my text-field and my select box to link and query the database, only one or the other. I want them both to work from the same button (search button)

```
<form  method="post" action="Webpage here"  id="searchform">
  <input  type="text" name="name">
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<form id="form1" name="ExamBoard" method="post" action="Webpage here">
  <label for="select"></label>
  <select name="ExamBoard" id="select">
    <option value="EB1" selected="selected">EB1</option>
    <option value="EB2">EB2</option>
    <option value="EB3">EB3</option>
  </select>
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 if(isset($_GET['go'])){
 if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['name'])){
 $name=$_POST['name'];
  //connect  to the database
 $db=mysql_connect  ("Name", "User",  "Password*") or die ('I cannot connect to the      database  because: ' . mysql_error());
 //-select  the database to use
 $mydb=mysql_select_db("Table Name");
  //-query  the database table
  $sql="SELECT  ID, CourseName, ExamBoard FROM subjects WHERE CourseName LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' ";
   //-run  the query against the mysql query function
   $result=mysql_query($sql);
    //-create  while loop and loop through result set
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $CourseName  =$row['CourseName'];
      $ID=$row['ID'];
      $ExamBoard=$row['ExamBoard'];
  //-display the result of the array
  echo "<ul>\n";
  echo "<li>" . "<a  href=\"search.php?id=$ID\">"   .$CourseName . " " .  "</a></li>\n" ;
  echo  $ExamBoard . " " .  "</a>\n";
  echo "</ul>";
  }
  }
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

New HTML File

newHTML.htm

```
<form  method="post" action="Webpage here"  id="searchform">
  <input  type="text" name="name">
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form
```

New PHP file

newPHP.pfp

```
<?php
 if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_REQUEST['name'])){
 $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
  //connect  to the database
 $db=mysql_connect  ("Name", "User",  "Password*") or die ('I cannot connect to the      database  because: ' . mysql_error());
 //-select  the database to use
 $mydb=mysql_select_db("Table Name");
  //-query  the database table
  $sql="SELECT  ID, CourseName, ExamBoard FROM subjects WHERE CourseName LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' ";
   //-run  the query against the mysql query function
   $result=mysql_query($sql);
    //-create  while loop and loop through result set
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $CourseName  =$row['CourseName'];
      $ID=$row['ID'];
      $ExamBoard=$row['ExamBoard'];
  //-display the result of the array
  echo "<ul>\n";
  echo "<li>" . "<a  href=\"search.php?id=$ID\">"   .$CourseName . " " .  "</a></li>\n" ;
  echo  $ExamBoard . " " .  "</a>\n";
  echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot this code worked and it was a great help. Have you got any tips on how to put a Select(Dropdown) box in there as well so it searches multiple requests, i.e from text input and dropdown at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself Do you want to do this with AJAX or with normal screen refreshes..

With normal screen refreshes (The easy way)

Take your HTML and place it in one file (HTMLfile.html)
Take your PHP and place it in another file (PHPCode.php)

HTML file form calls the PHP script from action attribute.

PHP file renders the response.

Dont mash up the view and the controlling application.

There is other ways to do this in one script if you want to use AJAX.

Comment: Hi user1551869, i have put all the HTML into 1 file and all the PHP into another. Do you know how i can get the php to search both form selectons?